# Unable to create Configuration Database...?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, administration, sharepointadmin

When running the SharePoint configuration wizard for the 1st time to configure Central Administration, the following error occurs:

> One or more configuration settings failed. Completed configuration settings will not be rolled back. Resolve the problem and run this configuration wizard again. The following contains detailed information about the failure:
>
> **Failed to create the configuration database.**
>
> An exception of type System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException was thrown. Additional exception information: **profile name is not valid**

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=sql+server+profile+name+is+not+valid - it looks like a SQL Server, not SharePoint, problem to me. It is not programming related so you should move the question to http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/ or http://dba.stackexchange.com/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not created the Profile name in SQL Server - that's why I was getting the error. Finally the problem is solved! I just created it.

Comment: Marek the problem was related to Sharepoint mainly. The Error comes while runnning the product configuration wizard in Sharepoint 2010 in step 3.